# Returning Values based on column data

Tags: excel

If anyone can help me please, I need to know how to return a result value in column C1. 
I have 3 columns A, B, C, if column A1 is X and column B1 is empty return value of A1, but if column A1 = X and B1 = Date then return value in column C1 = Repaired.

Cell A1 will have 17 vehicle reg numbers, would it be possible not to have duplicate results but instead have one result for each vehicle reg number.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: sorry, the 17 vehicles will be in column A starting from A1 but these vehicles can re-occur more than once.

Comment: yes, the re-occuring vehicle reg's will have more than one date. Basically I'm creating a vehicle defects log sheet and i need to note down all the defects within the vehicle, so for every vehicle will have more than one defect, if date is entered into column c then confirm that the vehicle has been repaired according to each specific vehicle reg, and if column C has no date then cell is still awaiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should sort everything out.

```
=IF(A1<>"",IF(B1="",A1,"Repaired"),"")
```

This can then be dragged down over as many columns as you want. This first `if` checks to see whether there is an entry in place in column A, so this will work whether a licence plate is there or not and will work if you need to add more or delete some entries from column A.

Comment: thanks, but instead of dragging and having duplicate values of the same thing would it be possible to just search for that specific vehicle reg in column A that has no date assigned in column B to display the vehicle reg in column c, in that way i can just tell which vehicle still needs repairing (ones that have no date which means its not repaired) instead of having to read the whole list with duplicates.

Comment: There are a variety of easier methods that may suit you better. For instance you could sort all the data so that the vehicle reg with no date assigned could be sort to the date minimising the amount of data you have to sift through. Or would you be more interested in a drop down menu to search for the rego number with no date assigned. That way you have only a button to click that lists just the rego numbers you are looking for?

Comment: i think the drop down menu to search for reg number sounds more interesting.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have written a macro for you to use. Any problems with it or anything else I can help you with just let me know. The upload location is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p89vlbtaagppbni/Registration%20Numbers.xlsm

Comment: thanks, I will try the macro tomorrow and let you know, does the macro just search for the missing fields that have no date?

Comment: Yes. I have listed cell A1 for Registration Numbers and B1 for a date input. Clicking on the Search button will bring up a list of all Registration numbers that do not have a date next to it. Any issues let me know.

Comment: ahh ok, since i will have duplicates in column A, will it be possible just to show one of each vehicle reg without date?

Comment: so what you want is one of each vehicle reg only if they don't have a date? will any duplicates of the vehicle reg not have dates or should only one vehicle registration in a set of duplicates not have a date.

Comment: Update file has been uploaded at [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgx7anbm6yfvz80/Registration%20Numbers-2.xlsm) provided.

Comment: in the list the vehicle reg numbers will re-occur but there will only be one date for one of each vehicle reg, so duplicates of reg will not show.

Comment: and you don't want duplicates to show? currently it will check the list to see if there **isn't** a date next to the reg number (just a blank space) and will only display those reg numbers once

Comment: [this should work](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgx7anbm6yfvz80/Registration%20Numbers-2.xlsm)